# Symfony3 and Sonata-adminBundle:dev-master Admin route is not automatically generated

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using symfony3 and sonata-project/admin-bundle:dev-master. my problem is that when I generate an Admin class by the command line: sonata:admin:generate, now when I try to access the admin dashboard in order to see my admin class...I get the following error: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_pa_pacomplaint_create" as such route does not exist.") in SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig at line 39.`

Edit: Event bin/console debug:router does not show the route of the newly created admin class

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my question where so easy: I just needed to update the app/config/routing.yml file with the following:

```
_sonata_admin:
resource: .
type: sonata_admin
prefix: /admin
```